# 'Date' datatype of a column is not updating in EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

Initially, for Date_IN column in my DB i set it as 'DateTime' datatype. Then due to some issues, i modified it to 'Date' datatype. But when i tried to update the model in Entity Framework by right clicking in the designer 'Update model from Database', the column datatype is not setting to 'Date' datatype.

**Modified datatype for Date_IN column:**

[image]

**Update Model from database**:
[image]

**Datetype not changed:**

[image]

In the properties for the column, i even could not find 'Date' datatype. Please check through the below images for further details. Please let me know how to proceed with this. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Date` type in C# (which is what it's showing you in the Type field).  So even if you change your data type in the database from `datetime` to `date` it will still map to a `DateTime` in your model in EF.